# How to restart the count of stanza (with reledpar)

Tags: reledpar

I am new to using Latex, and I hope my question is correct.
In the context of a critical edition, I need to count the stanzas (if possible in Roman numeral), and the count must restarted at each section.
Here is my code :

```
    \documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,twoside,a4paper]{memoir}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[francais,latin]{babel}
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{verse}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \usepackage[ widthliketwocolumns,
        nocritical,
        noeledsec,
        noend,
        nofamiliar,
        noledgroup,
        series={}
        ]{reledmac}
    \usepackage{reledpar}
    %%%%%%%
    \setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
    \setstanzaindents{0,0,0}
    \AtEveryStopStanza{\vspace{1\baselineskip}}
    \numberstanzatrue
    %%%%%
    \setlength{\Lcolwidth}{.630\textwidth}
    \setlength{\Rcolwidth}{.600\textwidth}
    \columnsposition{L}
    \setlength{\beforecolumnseparator}{0.030\textwidth}
    \setlength{\aftercolumnseparator}{0.030\textwidth}
    \AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%DOCUMENT%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
    \chapter*{Traduction des fragments}
    \section{Livius Andronicus}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \subsection*{Aegistus}
    \begin{pairs}
      \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
        \stanza
    Nam ut Pergama&
    Accensa et praeda per participes aequiter& 
    Partíta est\& 
         %
         \stanza
    Tum autem lasciuum Nerei simum pecus&
    Ludens ad cantum classem lustratur\& 
    \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
      \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
        \numberstanzafalse
        \stanza 
    Translation first verse& 
    Translation second verse& 
    Translation verse blablabla \&
     %
      \stanza 
    Translation blablabla& 
    Translation blablablabla\&
        \endnumbering
      \end{Rightside}
      \end{pairs}
      \Columns
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \subsection*{Iphigenia}
      \begin{pairs}
      \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
        \stanza
    Nisi patrem matemo sanguine exanclando ulciscerem\&
        %
        \stanza
    Id ego aecum fecisse expedibo atque eloquar&
    Quid noctis uidetur in altisono&
     Caeli clipeo?\&
     \endnumbering
        \end{Leftside}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%
      \begin{Rightside}
          \beginnumbering
          \numberstanzafalse
        \stanza
    Translation blalbalbal\& 
     %
      \stanza
    Translation first verse&
    Translation blabalbalbla&
    Translation bla\& %
        \endnumbering
      \end{Rightside}
    \end{pairs}
    \Columns
    \end{document}
```

I would also like to know how to include comments in the margin, for each stanza.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thestanzaL}{\textbf{\roman{stanzaL}}}` will change the stanza counter for the left column to roman numerals, use \Roman if you want capital letters. You can reset the left column stanza counter with `\setcounter{stanzaL}{0}` at any point, e.g. at the beginning of every section or subsection, there may be more elegant or automatic ways to do that though that I am not aware of.

Comment: That works well ! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @henryflower can you please turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`\renewcommand{\thestanzaL}{\textbf{\roman{stanzaL}}}` will change the stanza counter for the left column to roman numerals, use `\Roman` if you want capital letters. You can reset the left column stanza counter with `\setcounter{stanzaL}{0}` at any point, e.g. at the beginning of every section or subsection. There may be more elegant or automatic ways to do that though that I am not aware of.

The documentations for `reledmac` (p. 68) and `reledpar` (p. 22) explain about marginal notes, although I'd suspect your page would become very crowded when setting two columns in parallel and adding notes in either the columns or page margins.